# how to make accessibility focus stay inside current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, focusable, accessibility

How can I make `focus navigation` to stay inside the `current fragment?`
Or, how can I set `focusable` to false for a whole fragment or view with its all child view?

**full explanation:**

I'm making my Android app accessible.

I have this situation:

home fragment (A) is being covered by login fragment (B) after clicking on the title "log in". as you can see here:

[fragments diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKIuS.jpg)

after click on "log in", login fragment gets focus, and until clicking on `back` I want the `accessibility focus` to stay inside the login fragment (when the user navigate through focus navigation) rather then keep jumping between covered elements in fragment A.

How can I make focus navigation to stay inside fragment B?
Or, instead:

How can I set `focusable` to false for the all of the child views in fragment A?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an accessible modal dialog.  It's a pretty common thing.  Greg Kraus, the former accessibility guru at NCSU wrote a great blog on this topic - https://github.com/gdkraus/accessible-modal-dialog

You essentially need to create a big `<div>` to cover your main window and make the z-order on top of your main window.  This big `<div>` could have opacity set on it if want the main window to appear disabled.  The `<div>` doesn't accept any input so the user can't move the focus back to the main window.  Then your login dialog would have a z-order higher than the `<div>`.

Comment: link  is removed

Comment: NCSU reorganized their a11y documents and the link is no longer valid.  The blog article can be found at https://github.com/gdkraus/accessible-modal-dialog